# Query to get only tables that have at least one field of a certain type

Tags: sql, teradata, names

Is possible to get the table names of tables that have at least one field of a certain type in Teradata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon already wrote you need to query the data dictionary, just use the `V`-views instead (the old ones are deprecated since TD12):

```
select c.*
from dbc.columnsV c
where c.columntype = 'DA';
```

Check the [Data Dictionary manual](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1092_151K/Views_Reference.018.133.html) the correct abbreviation for each datatype

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DBC.COLUMNS`.  For instance, if you wanted all tables that had a column of date type:

```
select c.*
from dbc.columnc c
where c.columntype = 'DA';
```

This [posting](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/general/get-ddl-from-dbc-tables) provides more information.